# Want to use a text box where we can enter the path and then on button click the data populates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba macro which currently works in such a way that the filenames and the modified dates for each file is extracted in the excel sheet. But the problem is that I need to go to the macro and update the path each time. I want to have a text box where I can enter the path and then on button click the filenames and the date modified are extracted to the excel sheet. Below is the current code which I use:

```
Sub FileT()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempString As String


newString = Left(originalString, 1)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\rd4470\Documents\Test Folder")
i = 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
tempString = Left(objFile.Name, 1)
If tempString = "T" Then

    Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Name

    Cells(i + 1, 4) = objFile.DateLastModified

    i = i + 1
End If

    Next objFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of the text box for the path.  `objFSO.GetFolder(TextBox1.Text)`

```
Sub FileT()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempString As String

    newString = Left(originalString, 1)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(TextBox1.Text)
    i = 1

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        tempString = Left(objFile.Name, 1)
        If tempString = "T" Then

            Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Name

            Cells(i + 1, 4) = objFile.DateLastModified

            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next objFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input box for that purpose

```
sFldr = Application.InputBox("Enter path",,,,,,,2)
...
If Len(Dir(sFldr, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFldr)
    ...
End If
```